# Unable to add, commit, push new files/directories to Git: working tree clean

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit, bitbucket-server

We have a company Atlassian Bitbucket account which we use for our Source Control Management. I'm trying to add, commit and push files and directories in my project repo to the remote. However, it looks like Git doesn't recognize that new files are being added. It says my 'working tree is clean'.

[image]

I also tried other suggested solutions from same questions posted here in StackOverflow, links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067873/git-nothing-to-commit-working-directory-clean), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269222/git-status-nothing-to-commit-working-directory-clean-however-wth-changes-com), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745464/git-commit-problems). And nothing worked.

When I use TortoiseGit, here's how the `test` path looks like

[image]

Meaning, Git or TortoiseGit does not recognize it as part of repository. (Normally TortoiseGit has this red exclamation mark on the file if it's added or changed)

[image]

I edited the `README` file just to show that Git still works on that one. I can still commit and push it. I don't have any `gitignore` configuration.

I also added some text file (non-empty) within the project folder and the `test` folder.

[image]

[image]

Anyone here who has an idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you re-run `git add` after creating the `new` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your test folder is empty and git ignores all directories.

[Does git ignore empty folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030230/does-git-ignore-empty-folders)

Comment: I revised my post. Kindly look above.

Comment: Did you try git status --ignored and check if there is ~/.gitignore_global file and check inside .git/info/exclude

Comment: Your correct, it's because the folders are empty. I think the reason the TortoiseGit icon's not immediately updating on created files it's because I am connected to remote repo via VPN. The icon would update after some minutes. Thanks for your help.